# Default activity

Tags: android

I am reading a tutorial and the default activity is a class that extends another, and all that it has is an overriden method. How does the application work since it doesn't do anything else? I am very confused!

Comment: You should gain the knowledge in OOPS and java to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent class `Activity` handles everything for you.

Comment: I would really appreciate something more specific.

Comment: You can't see any of the code in the activity class.  The override method that you see is where you put your code. I'm guessing you probably are looking at onCreate().  This is where you would initialize all of your controls that are in your xml file. I would strongly recommend looking at some of the demo applications.

Comment: wait wait, the class i look is the default one (to be clear, it's this: <activity android:name="MyGame...>"). it's the one that as i previously said includes only an overriden method. does the flow continues because its' superclass is being automatically instantiated? because as you said, if i check the onCreate() method everything seems normal to my eyes :P

Comment: Yes. It is automatically instantiated.  Also the super class methods are called from the subclass methods.  For example in your onCreate method there should be a line of code that automatically calls the super class onCreate.  It should look something like this: super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: ah ok, that makes sense. is this just a java thing which obviously i didnt know or android specific?

Comment: Technically speaking it's a java thing, but the Android parent classes probably have a lot more "hidden" code than other java libraries you may work with.  Could you please mark this answer as correct if it has answered your question? I would be happy to offer more support if needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Its a **framework**. By extending `Activity`, your activity inherits **basic functionality**. If you want to add/change something, you need to override its methods.
But even though, not all application functionality is inside your activity. You are basically writing components. The Android plattform will *use* them. This is why you need a reference to them in your Manifest file.

Btw; no offense, but if you demand more specific answers, you should specify your question first.